# Regex uppercase certain letters

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use regex to uppercase the letter c in certain circumstances (e.g.) if the C is for Celsius. My regex so far:

```
((?!\s)[c](?=\s)|(?!\d)[c](?=\d)|[c](?=-))
```

Example text:

```
Some plastic insert c lids were cracked, temperature was between 8c and 8.8c.
```

I want to capitalize all the solitary c's and the c's after the numbers. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `(?<=...)` instead of `(?!...)`, the former stands for *look behind* while the latter stands for *negative look ahead*, if you want to replace `c` after space or digits, then you need to use *look behind* constraint:

```
str1 = "Some plastic insert c lids were cracked, temperature was between 8c and 8.8c."

import re
re.sub(r"(?<=\s)c(?=\s)|(?<=\d)c", "C", str1)
# 'Some plastic insert C lids were cracked, temperature was between 8C and 8.8C.'
```

Depending on how you define solitary, a word boundary might be better suited:

```
re.sub(r"\bc\b|(?<=\d)c", "C", str1)
# 'Some plastic insert C lids were cracked, temperature was between 8C and 8.8C.'
```

*Update* for the case in the comment:

```
str2 = "Ensure that noodles soaked in water are kept at or 4 c. Noodles are moved to walk in cooler. * Ensure that perishable food is chilled rapidly as * A) temperature from 60 c-20 C must fall within two hrs"

re.sub(r"\bc\b|(?<=\d)c", "C", str2)
# 'Ensure that noodles soaked in water are kept at or 4 C. Noodles are moved to walk in cooler. * Ensure that perishable food is chilled rapidly as * A) temperature from 60 C-20 C must fall within two hrs'
```

Comment: i think this will be better `r'(?<=[\s\d])c(?=\s|$)|(?<=^)c(?=\s)'`

Comment: @rock321987 absolutely, It depends on what OP means for the solitary. Added a more general word boundary option for it.

Comment: I tried these, and some c's are missed: "Ensure that noodles soaked in water are  kept at or 4 c. Noodles are moved to walk in cooler.
 * Ensure that perishable food is chilled rapidly as
 * A) temperature from 60 c-20 C must fall within two hrs"

Comment: Did you try the second version? It is working for me. All three c are capitalized after the `sub`.

Comment: Yes I did. I still get "4 c" and "c-20". Works on all other instances perfectly.

Comment: Use a boundary for the lookahead: [**`(?<=[\s\d])c\b`**](https://regex101.com/r/bV8mA8/1)

Comment: Updated this case in the answer, seems to be working for me.

Comment: I ended up with `\bc\b|(?<=[\s\d])c(?=\s|$)|(?<=^)c(?=\s)|(?<=\d)[c](?=\.)` to catch some edge cases.